# Verify that $x = −(I − A^{\dagger}A)c$ optimises $ \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \langle c,x \rangle$ under constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

Under the constraint that $Ax = 0$ and $A$ is full row rank, how would you get the solution to the optimisation problem $$\text{min } \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \langle c,x \rangle$$

My text says that $x = −(I − A^{\dagger}A)c$ is a unique solution but I am unsure as to how to verify it as I am unsure what a feasible direction is under this constraint.

$A^{\dagger}$ is the Moore Penrose inverse

Comment: You may try to set the problem in terms of Lagrange multipliers. That will give you a linear equation that can be solve in terms of $A^+$.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Another way to think about this is as follows

Note that

$$\frac{1}{2}\|x-(-c)\|_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|c\|^2 + c^Tx.$$

Now we want $x$ to be in the Null space of $A$ and hence we look at the projection of $-c$ onto the null space of $A$.

---

Let $u$ be the projection of $c$ onto the null space of $A$. Let $v$ be such that $c = u+v$ and $v \in \mathcal{N}(A)^\perp$. Then we have that for any $x \in \mathcal{N}(A)$ we have that

$$c^Tx = u^Tx.$$

Thus our objective is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + u^Tx.$$

Suppose this was unconstrained, then taking the derivative and setting it to $0$, we get

$$ x +u = 0 \Rightarrow x = -u.$$

Now $-u \in \mathcal{N}(A)$, hence this is the constrained solution as well.

Finally note that $(I-A^\dagger A)$ is the projection matrix for $
\mathcal{N}(A)$. Thus,

$$-(I-A^\dagger A)c = -u.$$

Comment: How does the projection matrix make it a unique solution? Is the following correct: I understand that for a matrix A, P = $A^{\dagger} A$ is is an orthogonal projection onto the range of A, and since range of P is orthogonal to range of (I-P), $I - A^{\dagger} A$  projects onto null(A) (null(A) is orthogonal to col(A)). Since c is in column space of A, then the projection of c into the null space of A is the solution?

Comment: So the uniqueness comes from the fact that we optimizing a convex function over a linear subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Making the Lagrangian

$$L(x,\lambda)= \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \langle c,x \rangle-\lambda^TA x$$

the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
x^T+c^T-\lambda^T A=0\Rightarrow x^T = -c^T + \lambda^T A
$$

but as $\lambda$ is generic, there exists $B$ generic such that $\lambda^T = c^T B$ and then

$$
x^T = -c^T(I-B A)
$$

or

$$
x = -(I-A^TB^T)c
$$

so we know the solution structure and we can argue for the solution to

$$
\min_B \frac 12 c^T(I-B A)(I-A^TB^T)c-c^T(I-B A)c
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix.

*Fact 1*: If $A$ is full low rank,
then $A^\dagger = A^\mathsf{T}(A A^\mathsf{T})^{-1}$. Also,
$(I - A^\dagger A)^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A) = I - A^\dagger A$.

*Fact 2*: All solutions of $Ax = 0$ are given by $x = (I - A^\dagger A)y$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is arbitrary.

Using Facts 1-2, equivalently, we turn to find $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$f(y) = \frac12\|(I - A^\dagger A)y\|^2 + \langle c, (I - A^\dagger A)y \rangle$$
is minimized.

Using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(y) &= \frac12 y^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A)^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A)y + c^\mathsf{T} (I - A^\dagger A)y \\
 &= \frac12 y^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A)^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A) y + c^\mathsf{T} (I - A^\dagger A)^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A)y \\
 &= \frac12\|(I - A^\dagger A)y + (I - A^\dagger A)c\|^2 - \frac12 c^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A)^\mathsf{T}(I - A^\dagger A) c.
\end{align*}
Thus, any global minimizer of $f(y)$
satisfies $(I - A^\dagger A)y + (I - A^\dagger A)c = 0$ or
$(I - A^\dagger A)y = - (I - A^\dagger A)c$.
Thus, $x = - (I - A^\dagger A)c$ is the unique global minimizer of the original problem.